# Why is my WCF proxy client not strongly typed?

Tags: wcf

I'm having a problem with my WCF generated proxies - they work, but are not strongly typed. On the server side, a method is defined thus:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all ElementSetTypes.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>All ElementSetTypes</returns>
[OperationContract]
IList<IElementSetType> GetElementSetTypeList();
```

When I generate the proxy, the client's signature looks like this:

```
object[] GetElementSetTypeList();
```

This applies to all my types across the interface, whether a return type or a method parameter, they are replaced with 'object'. What reason might there be for this?

Comment: Do you have a DataContract and DataMembers on your interface: IElementSetType?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Use Interface as DataContract in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841636/how-to-use-interface-as-datacontract-in-wcf)

Comment: @peer - I have DataContract and DataMembers set up on the ElementSetType, not the IElementSetType.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I'm reusing both interfaces and implementations on the server side, so I don't want to use different implementations of the data types.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108076/wcf-interface-return-type-and-knowntypes. I mean: show what you have tried and found, "wcf datacontract return interface" gives a lot of hits, the solution is the `(Service)KnownType` attribute.

Comment: You can't serialize an interface.  You'll either have to look at one of the examples posted by CodeCaster or cast the returned object to the right type that implements that interface.